# When I use flock it exits immediately instead of waiting

Tags: flock

I was confused for a very long time with the meaning of the `-n` flag for `flock(1)`.

Basically there are many guides for this tool, and often what we see is some command like `flock -n 100`. Here, fd number 100 is associated with some lockfile and used to perform locking.

Today I kept getting confused because I would do some simple tests, and `flock` would exit with failure immediately.

What exactly does the `-n` flag of `flock` do? Am I right in thinking that `-n 100` associates file descriptor number 100 with some lockfile?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but could you please make it an actual question? I don't understand what you are asking here.

Comment: Yeah let me figure out what would have been the burning question i had from before i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a long time to figure out that I misunderstood and made a dangerous assumption. I assumed from seeing it called with `-n 100` to specify fd 100, that `-n` was the flag to set the file descriptor number. This isn't the case.

`-n` is for nonblocking and this flag causes the immediate failure upon failure to lock. From `man flock`:

> -n, --nb, --nonblock
>
> Fail rather than wait if the lock cannot be immediately acquired.
> See the -E option for the exit status used.

It seems that if a plain number is given, then it is treated as the fd. This is nonobvious.

Comment: *This is nonobvious*  As far as I can tell it's documented in the flock(1) man page.  The `Synopsis` section at the top gives three examples of the command and argument syntax, and the third syntax is `flock [options] number`.  The `Description` section (just under Synopsis) describes the three syntaxes.   The first two don't show **number** as an argument.  The description of the third syntax says: `The third form uses an open file by its file descriptor number. See the examples below for how that can be used.`

Comment: The manpage definitely did clear it all up for me. I suppose that my point is that the examples I saw and the choice of having the short flag named `n` turned out to be misleading for me. I made this post because it's going to help out others who get confused in the same process.